# Eclipse SWT CellEditor Combo - autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a `TreeViewerColumn` with `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor` editing support. Now when I use normal Combo i can add autocomplete functionality like this:

```
new AutoCompleteField(myCombo, new ComboContentAdapter(), valuesArray);
```

but I found no way to add this functionality to combo inside my TreeViewer.

I have my ovn editing support implemented with `protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)` method implemented to return ComboBoxViewerCellEditor in some cases but I cant find a way to add autocomplete function here. Any ideas?

Comment: `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor` uses `CCombo` rather than `Combo`. There is no content adapter for `CCombo` so this would have to be written.

Comment: Oh I see it now, any hints how to implement this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write semething like this
`new AutoCompleteField(treeviewer.getControl(), new CComboContentAdapter(), valueArray);` and to get `CComboContentAdapter` You can copy the source code of `ComboContentAdapter` and replace 
`Combo` by `CCombo`

Comment: @unique_ptr any example for demo...i'm understand properly..thanks